# Skype 4.3 can not connect on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, skype, connection, microsoft

In Ubuntu 18.04 `x86_64`, I installed Skype 4.3 from `snap`. After setting the username and password (I checked them), any login attempt fails after a long wait: "Skype can not connect".

Then, I uninstalled it and used the `.deb` package provided [in the official site](https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb): `sudo gdebi skypeforlinux-64.deb`. It's, again, Skype 4.3. However, nothing changed. After a long wait, "Skype can not connect".

What could it be the problem?

Could it be a firewall issue? I never set any port or firewall rule on my host.

Comment: on that same machine can you reach the net ? is your browser OK  ...  from a terminal ( ctrl + alt + t )  issue a   `ping google.com`  to confirm you can reach the net ...  no you should not have to deal with firewall ... however its bizarre you say its Skype 4.3 when on ubuntu 18.04 `snap` is giving Skype version 8.57.0.116  ...  are you running system updates regularly ?  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ... update your snap by issuing `snap refresh`

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes, of course. I can ping to sites and normally browse the web. Otherwise, I would not be able even to download the [deb](https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I had a previously installed `i386` version of Skype, which I guess overlapped with the new `.deb` (64 bit) package. I made `sudo apt purge skype` and all the packages `skype:i386*` have been removed.

It now correctly works (I guess from the `.deb` installation). Version is not 4.3, but 8.57.0.116. It is the current version [in the official site](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa34778/what-s-new-in-skype-for-windows-mac-linux-and-web).